# Deserializing JSON in Java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the following sample fragment of JSON I am trying to deserialize.

```
{
    "total": 2236,
    "issues": [{
        "id": "10142",
        "key": "ID-2",
        "fields": {
            "attachment": [{
                "id": "11132"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I can deserialize the data up to id and key, but cannot deserialize attachments that is in fields. My attachment class is always null

Here's my code.

Response.java

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty
    private int total;

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Issue> issues; 
}
```

Issue.java

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Issue {

    @JsonProperty
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String key;

    @JsonProperty
    private Fields fields;
}
```

Fields.java

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Fields {

    @JsonProperty
    private Attachments attachment;
}
```

Attachments.java

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Attachments {

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Attachment> attachment; 
}
```

Attachments.java

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Attachment {

    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of each variable in your Java classes as corresponding to an attribute in the JSON. "Attachments" is not in the JSON file. You should be able to remove it and change the variable definition in the `Fields` class.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Fields {

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Attachment> attachment;
}
```

Comment: As per Arnaud's comment, that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I have cut and pasted the JSON into a file tmp.json and `python -mjson.tool tmp,json` complains: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 5 column 22 (char 71) - ah, sorry, I forgot to fix up the typographic quotes.

Comment: I have created a project with the suggested code (credit should go to Arnaud, I did not realise my code was the same) and it seems to work just fine.  Not sure why you suggested that it does not work, @user2254180?

Comment: One thing I did was remove the @Data annotation as this does not seem to come from Jackson?

Comment: With the code Arnaud and I suggested, did you get the same effect? (null values?)

Comment: The @Data is just lombok, I tried taking it out to see if that is the issue. It didn't help, values still returning as null for the attachment related classes

Comment: Apologies, I was doing something very silly in my code which I just fixed. Your suggestion works great now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your JSON, `attachment` is an array, not an object.

You don't need an `Attachments` class, just modify `Fields` this way:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Fields {

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Attachment> attachment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change class structure then, you can modify JSON.
In `attachment`, you need to add again an `attachment`.
JSON would be like below.

```
{
   "total":2233,
   "issues":[
      {
         "id":"13598",
         "key":"ID-2368",
         "fields":{
            "attachment":{
               "**attachment**":[
                  {
                     "id":"11122"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately modifying the source JSON is not an option.